# How to efficiently filter rows from geopandas df that are not within the bounds of a shapely polygon?

Tags: python, pandas, geospatial, geopandas, shapely

I have a regular pandas dataframe that i do a one time conversion to geopandas like so

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point
import geopandas
geo_df = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(input_df, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(input_df.Longitude, input_df.Latitude))
```

I also have a list of coordinates that i convert into a Shapely Polygon like so:

```
grid_polygon = Polygon(shape_coordinates)
```

I then want to filter all the rows in `geo_df` that are not within the bounds of the shapely polygon `grid_polygon`.

My current approach to accomplish this is:

```
geo_df['withinPolygon'] = ""
withinQlist = []
for lon,lat in zip(geo_df['longitude'], geo_df['latitude']):
    pt = Point(lon, lat)
    withinQ = pt.within(grid_polygon)
    withinQlist.append(withinQ)
geo_df['withinPolygon'] = withinQlist
geo_df = geo_df[geo_df.withinPolygon==True]
```

But this is pretty inefficient. I figure there is a way to do this without iterating over every row but most solutions I have been able to find do not filter using a shapely polygon. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Using `geo_df.apply()` should be slightly faster than a for loop but unless the `Point` constructor/check can be vectorized, you'll have to iterate over all the rows.

Comment: thanks - yes apply is one option but i think there is a more native way to do this - i believe the casting to Point here is actually not necessary - the necessary info should already be encoded  by the points_from_xy in the init of the geopandas df. i am currently trying to use logic df[df.geometry.within(polygon)] but still testing.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63369715/filter-a-geopandas-dataframe-within-a-polygon-and-remove-from-the-dataframe-the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first step, as you already mentioned in your comment, your code can be simplified like so:

```py
import geopandas
geo_df = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(input_df, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(input_df.Longitude, input_df.Latitude)

geo_df_filtered = geo_df.loc[geo_df.within(grid_polygon)]
```

But there are a few techniques for speeding that up, depending on what kind of data and usage patterns you have:

### Using a prepared geometry

If your polygon is very complex, creating a [prepared geometry](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#prepared.prep) will speed up the containment check.
This will pre-calculate various data structures once at the beginning, speeding up subsequent operations.
(More details [here](http://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.com/2007/08/preparedgeometry-efficient-batch.html).)

```py
from shapely.prepared import prep

grid_polygon_prep = prep(grid_polygon)
geo_df_filtered = geo_df.loc[geo_df.geometry.apply(lambda p: grid_polygon_prep.contains(p))]
```

(Cannot just do `geo_df.loc[geo_df.within(grid_polygon_prep)]` like above, as geopandas does not support prepared geometries here.)

### Using a spatial index

If you need to run the containment check for a given set of points against many `grid_polygon`s, not just one, then using a spatial index over these points makes sense.
It will speed things up significantly, especially when there are lots of points.

Geopandas provides [`GeoDataFrame.sindex.query`](https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/sindex.html) for that:

```py
match_indices = geo_df.sindex.query(grid_polygon, predicate="contains")
# note that using `iloc` instead of `loc` is important here
geo_df_filtered = geo_df.iloc[match_indices]
```

Nice blogpost with some more explanations: https://geoffboeing.com/2016/10/r-tree-spatial-index-python/